# Cmake and eclipse multiple targets

Tags: eclipse, cmake, target

I am new in the cmake world and I am not even sure if what I try to achieve is possible or not.

Currently, I have an eclipse project file which contains many targets (they have some files in common, some are different (I used the exclusions in Eclipse to do it)).

One of my colleague uses the CLion for that so he created a CmakeLists.txt files for that. **Is it possible to use these CmakeLists.txt files to create a project in eclipse? Is it possible to have this way a multiple targets in one project file?**

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use these CmakeLists.txt files to create a project in eclipse?

Yes, use the following from your source root to generate Eclipse project files which support in-source builds.

```
$ cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" .
```

If you want to do out-of-source builds, there are a few wrinkles to be aware of. Have a look at [this cmake wiki page](https://cmake.org/Wiki/Eclipse_CDT4_Generator) about the Eclipse CDT generator for more details.

Note that Eclipse also supports importing projects from existing makefiles, which means you can just use the "Unix Makefile" generator to generate makefiles, and import from those.

See [this cmake wiki page](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:Eclipse_UNIX_Tutorial) for details on that

> Is it possible to have this way a multiple targets in one project file?

Yes it is. All targets specified in your `CMakeLists.txt` file(s) will be included in the generated project file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for a quick answer. I looked into what you sent me but my indexing still does not work. In my project I have following structure: 
Folder main with main.c
Folder platform with three different folders: folder a with a.c file, folder b with b.c file and folder c.c file, and one platform.h file common for all those files with declaration of function "platform()". The main function calls the function "platform()" from platform.h which definition is different for each target (a, b, and c respectively defined in a.c, b.c and c.c file). When I create the eclipse project I do get the folder called "[Targets]" but the indexing does not work which means it does not show me the function from the proper target.

Is it possible to be able to switch from one target to another with the "hammer" sign?

Many thanks.